# Repeat Keys in Hash

Tags: ruby

My Hash:

```
@round=0
@round+=1
@people={"TestUser1"=>3, "AnotherTest2"=>4, "NewOne3"=>5, "TestTest4"=>6, "Help"=>7}
```

I am making an UNO game, where TestUser1 keeps going in a circle around AnotherTest2, NewOne3, TestTest4, and REPEAT.

I did: `@people.keys[@round-1]`
=> TestUser1 | AnotherTest2 | TestTest4 | Help. After that, it does not repeat again, how could I make it to repeat it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Enumerable#cycle`:

```
@people.keys.cycle.each do |person|
  break if rand < 0.01 # or some better termination condition
  puts person
end
```

Comment: The results were not in order. Results were: TestUser1 -> AnotherTest2 -> NewOne3 -> TestTest4 -> Help5 -> TestUser1 -> AnotherTest2 -> TestUser1, TestTest4. It's supposed to be 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 and it puts out 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 1 4

Comment: I wanted somehow to make it go around and around, Repeating users 1 2 3 4 5 over and over again. @amadan

Comment: A hash is unordered: the only guarantee you get from `keys` is that it will return each key exactly once. If you need a specific order, keep an array of players separate from the hash, and cycle on that. Try it: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].cycle.take(20)`. If you mean they were not in the same order in each cycle, that means you were doing something weird that is not represented in my code.